# transformations data Pyspark python

Tags: python, if-statement, pyspark

**how to write statement python Python Functions?**

I want to change data(Million Records) l = 0, m = 1, h = 2, c= 3 ,cause I'll find average later. I use 'Order Priority' as id but string can't `reduceByKey`.

My data looks like the following:

```
+--------------+------------+
|Order Priority|  Units Sold|
+--------------+------------+
|M             |1593        | 
|M             |4611        |
|C             |7676        | 
|H             |4790        | 
|L             |3973        |
```

L = Low, M = Medium, H = High, C= Critical

This my code.py:

```
def parseLine(line):
    fields = line.split(',')
    priority = (fields[0])
    sold = float(fields[1])
    return (priority, sold)


lines = sc.textFile("file:///SparkCourse/project/1MillSalesRecords.csv", 4)
rdd = lines.map(parseLine)

print(rdd.take(2))
```

result:

`[('M', 1593.0), ('M', 4611.0)]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want a scalable approach, use another map function that replaces the letter with the number you want. In this approach I create a string with the mapping letters and then look up what index the incoming letter is in.

Feel free to also merge this function with the first map (parser)

```
def cleanLine(line):
    #Get the character index 
    letter_index = 'LMHC'.find(line[0])
    return (letter_index , line[1])

cleanedLine = rdd.map(cleanLine)
print(cleanedLine.take(2))
```

Comment: sorry, I am just a beginner. error : `letter_index = 'LMHC'.find(line._1)
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute '_1'`

Comment: my bad. I meant to call `map()` on the `rdd` element since that has the parsed lines from the previous map. I edited my answer

Comment: again my bad. I was working in Scala. Now this should be working in pyspark